# Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am playing with matrices and linear transformation so I was searching for matrix to transfer the 2d space vector into 2d circle so any line can be transferred into circle

Comment: $S^1$ isn't usually considered a vector space.  Is there some sense of addition and scalar multiplication on $S^1$ that you've defined that makes it one?

Comment: But why is that?  I mean the number line it self is considered to be 1-d vector space and the x-y in the sense of Cartesian coordinates is considered to be 2-d vector space (of course here I mean the linear relation in the space like x=3y for example not x^2) so why we cannot consider it vector space? Right?

Comment: Because those sets satisfy all the [vector space axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).  Not every set does.  In paricular notice that we need to define addition and scalar multiplication.  And that those operations have to have a bunch of properties.